# Numerical Computing

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, graph-theory, numerical-methods

i want to solve the following system  of ODE's , doesn't matter which methods you use.
the system is the following:

$\frac{dp}{dt}= -Lp-k_1p-k_{12}p\tilde{p} + k_0$

$\frac{d\tilde{p}}{dt}= -L\tilde{p}-(\tilde{k_1}+\gamma c )\tilde{p}-k_{12}p\tilde{p} $

$\frac{dc}{dt}= -\mu L c-k_{12}\tilde{p} $

where $k_1=k_{12}=\tilde{k_1}=0.5 ;  k_0=1; \mu= 0.3 ;\gamma=0.6 $ are parameters

where L is a laplacian matrix of size 83x83

The initial condition are:

$\epsilon = 1e-1;$

$p_0 = ones(N,1); $

$p_0(27) = 1-eps;$

$ p_0(68) = 1-eps;$

$\tilde{p}_0 = 1 - p_0;$

$c_0=ones(N,1);$

$c_0(27)=50;$

Comment: So what's your actual question? Do you want, for example, an explanation of how to code a Runge-Kutta treatment of this?

Comment: What mathematical software do you have available?  Maple, Matlab, Mathematica?  Don't try to program your own ODE solver.

Comment: actually i've solved with matlab